# Iterate list on query string element by element

Tags: python, rest, loops, for-loop, iteration

I have a list of elements I want to put into a url individually, read the download as csv and name it based on the element. Then proceed to the next element on the list.

For example (made up address):

Input `list = ['1','2','3'] query_string = f'https://query.number.com/download/{list}&real=true`

Output I would like is `df_1 = pd.read_csv('https://query.number.com/download/{1}&real=true') df_2 = ('https://query.number.com/download/{2}&real=true') df_3 = ('https://query.number.com/download/{3}&real=true')`

I assume a for loop is neccessary but unsure how to complete the process for the first element before moving onto the next as it current creates:

`query_string = f'https://query.number.com/download/{'1','2','3'}` which creates an error particularly as the list is 100 elements

Any help is hugely appreciated or resources to learn more, please feel free to connect as I want to grow my coding community! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
l = [1, 2, 3, 4]
urls = [f'https://query.number.com/download/{i}' for i in l]
```

Is that what you want?

Comment: Sorry no because this then creates 4 copies of https://query.number.com/download/{1,2,3,4}

as opposed to https://query.number.com/download/{1}, https://query.number.com/download/{2}

Does that make sense? Thanks!

Comment: No, it doesn't. Did you check my code? It creates 4 strings:
['https://query.number.com/download/1', 'https://query.number.com/download/2', 'https://query.number.com/download/3', 'https://query.number.com/download/4']

Comment: Thank you, you are right, before I had typed in l instead of i which was why it printed the whole list.

This still means I have to copy and paste 100 links into the search bar and then have 100 smaller datasets to merge. Do you think there is a better way? Thanks for your help s0mbre

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you are trying to do ultimately. Your initial question was, how to generate a list of URLs given a list of variables (like 1, 2, 3...) - right? So I've shown that it's very simple. If your task is to actually download the files and process them, then please reformulate your question.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether I get it. It seems that you should not put that list in `query_string` at the very beginning.

Besides, `list` is a built-in type in Python, so it is not suggested to name any variable after `list`.

```py
ele = ['1', '2', '3']
query_string = 'https://query.number.com/download/{}'
for e in ele:
    do_sth(query_string.format(e))
    output_name = 'df_{}'.format(e)
```

If you prefer f-strings:

```py
ele = ['1', '2', '3']
query_string = 'https://query.number.com/download'
for e in ele:
    do_sth(f'{query_string}/{e}')
    output_name = f'df_{e}'
```

Comment: Sorry I edited my question to hopefully explain what I am trying to do better, are you saying it is not beneficial to use lists to iterate through variables? What would you use instead thanks

Comment: No, I am saying that your `list` should not be directly put into the `query_string`@Josh

Comment: I see, how would you solve this when the variable is not at the end of the website link?

Comment: In the first case of my answer, `query_string = 'https://query.number.com/download/{}/something_else'`; in the second case, `do_sth(f'{query_string}/{e}/something_else')`

Comment: Thank you Zebartin, this makes sense. Sorry if this is really silly, I substituted in 
    pd.read_csv(query_string.format(i))
    output)name = 'df_{}'.format(i)

But this doesn't give me the data set, why would this be? Does it need to download before I name it? Sorry if its super obvious

Comment: Generally `pd.read_csv()` reads a local file instead of the resource on the network. I think you should download the dataset using [requests](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/) or some other modules.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a list to hold the dfs, and read the csv into a new df, then append to your list of dfs. I'm not sure why you want 100 different dfs.  If you then want to do something with your dfs in the list of dfs, you can save to a file, etc. using the df's index in the list of dfs.

Normally I would have 1 giant df and put the 1, 2, 3 inputs as a value in one of the columns.  Then you can filter the df based on the input column.

```
list_of_dfs = []
giant_df = pd.DataFrame()

input_list = ['1', '2', '3']
for inp in input_list:
    # get the df for this csv
    df = pd.read_csv('https://query.number.com/download/' + inp)
    
    # append to your list of dfs
    list_of_dfs.append(df)

    # or to keep it all in 1 df:
    df['input'] = inp
    giant_df = giant_df.append(df)

# to filter a df with only the input 1
df1 = giant_df[giant_df['input'] == '1']
```

Comment: Thank you Hammurabi, this looks brilliant, there is certainly potential for so many data frames to get confusing, the issue I have is they all have the same column names and I thought it could be easier to rename the columns ie decimals_1, decimals_2 after I had downloaded the csvs. If you think there is a better way I would be happy to try it and would love to chat further with you about this.

Comment: Normally I would not rename the columns, just use the input as a column (as in the giant_df) if you need to distinguish different sources.

Comment: That makes sense, because the web address doesnt finish with inp it doesn't recognise the input list any advice?